# Alfresco RM site permission issue

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am able to assign the roles to four custom group(Admin,Record manager,User,Info) as well as created the file plan category in particular agency(for instance, agency1).Then created the Agency admin(for instance,agency1 admin) for the particular agency(for instance, agency1).Based on the group needs to assign the contributor permission for admin as well as consumer permission for Record manager,user and info group.But If I create the another agency admin(for instance,agency2 admin).If I login to agency2 admin and assigned contributor permission,while viewing the file plan category got two categories agency1 and agency2.

Need to restrict the access to show only agency1 file plan category while agency1 admin login under the Record management site.Please help to achieve in alfresco webscript.

Comment: Sorry, but could you re-write your question. It's not really clear.

Comment: Thanks.For instance, two agencies as user named Agency1 and Agency2.And has the category as(category_agency1) for agency1 and another category as (category_agency2).If Agency1 user logs, should see only category as(category_agency1) and same criteria holds for agency2 user.Resolved by creating the node and passing the node details to record management post webservice(api/node/"+Q.storeType+"/"+Q.storeId+"/"+Q.Id+"/rmpermissions",) as well as passing the permissions as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by creating the node and passing the node details to record management post webservice(api/node/"+Q.storeType+"/"+Q.storeId+"/"+Q.Id+"/rmpermissions",) as well as passing the permissions as data.